# How to hide wget output in Linux?

Tags: linux, bash, wget

I don't want to see any message when I use `wget`. I want to suppress all the output it normally produces on the screen.

How can I do it?

Comment: In [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) they mention a valid question as one that covers _software tools commonly used by programmers_ and is _a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development_. I think this is the case here, and for this I vote for reopening (note [the reformatting](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/30123463/revisions)) I did some time ago with this goal.

Comment: I agree, this should be reopened

Comment: The single answer here is sufficient, so I don't think this needs to be re-opened, but with > 100 votes on the question and > 200 votes on the single answer, it tells me that moderators sometimes miss the mark on what does or does not meet the guidelines.

Answer (score 222, accepted):

Why don't you use `-q`?

From `man wget`:

```
-q
--quiet
   Turn off Wget's output.
```

#### Test

```
$ wget www.google.com
--2015-05-08 14:07:42--  http://www.google.com/
Resolving www.google.com (www.google.com)... 
  (...)
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/html]
Saving to: ‘index.html’

    [ <=>                                                                                       ] 17,913      --.-K/s   in 0.01s   

2015-05-08 14:07:42 (1.37 MB/s) - ‘index.html’ saved [17913]
```

And:

```
$ wget -q www.google.com
$
```

Comment: Would be nice to be able to use --quiet and still get the last line of saved file.